# MongoDB Join filter, input, as, if, eq _id exists

Tags: mongodb, filter, left-join, inner-join, aggregation

"Updated" I would like the details(found in the card schema) to be inserted into the catagory.cards array. So that I can map the results and use the code below for example.

items[i].catagory[a].cards[c].image

---

2 schemas users and cards

I have user.catagories stored under user.catagory and cards associated with the catagory.cards listed in an array.
I have all the card data stored in a cards schema. (see below)

user & cards

```
    db={
  "User": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "650ee3f7f19dcf3789acdee1"
      },
      "verified": true,
      "catagory": [
        {
          "name": "trade",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-01T21:47:34.215Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65bc1176cfb7da6997273ae3"
          },
          "cards": [
            {
              "$oid": "65c43a9539206da4c953e334"
            },
            {
              "$oid": "65c43a9539206da4c953e32e"
            },
            {
              "$oid": "65c43a9539206da4c953e332"
            },
            {
              "$oid": "65d2447cbad1f058de61ecca"
            },
            {
              "$oid": "65d2447cbad1f058de61ecca"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "baseball",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-01T23:12:46.996Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65bc256ecfb7da6997273c71"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "hockey",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-14T00:56:49.771Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65cc0fd1fa50656dceec84af"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "mma",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-14T21:10:46.101Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65cd2c56db3d4b491e98a1e5"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "football",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-17T01:47:47.492Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65d010432c4c6cd6b8b83682"
          },
          "cards": [
            {
              "$oid": "65d2447cbad1f058de61ecd1"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "ufc",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-17T01:48:11.291Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65d0105b2c4c6cd6b8b836a6"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "test",
          "createdAt": {
            "$date": "2024-02-17T03:21:42.524Z"
          },
          "_id": {
            "$oid": "65d026462c4c6cd6b8b836dc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "cards": [
    {
      "_id": "65c43a9539206da4c953e334",
      "title": "PSA 9 1996 Topps Finest Gold w/ Coating #269 Kobe Bryant Rookie Card",
      "date": "2023-11-16T05:00:00.000Z",
      "price": 125000,
      "image": "s-l300.webp",
      "search": [],
      "createdAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "65c43a9539206da4c953e32e",
      "title": "1996-97 Topps Finest Bronze Refractor #74 Kobe Bryant (RC) PSA 7 W/ Coating",
      "date": "2024-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
      "price": 130000,
      "image": "s-l300.webp",
      "search": [],
      "createdAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "65c43a9539206da4c953e332",
      "title": "1996-97 Fleer Ultra Series 2 Basketball Factory Sealed Hobby Box-Kobe Bryant RC?",
      "date": "2023-11-28T05:00:00.000Z",
      "price": 124999,
      "image": "s-l300.webp",
      "search": [],
      "createdAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
      "__v": 0
    },
    {
      "_id": "65d2447cbad1f058de61ecca",
      "title": "HUGE SPORTS CARD COLLECTION! 2023 CJ Stroud Justin Herbert Rookie Auto RPA READ",
      "date": "2024-02-17T05:00:00.000Z",
      "price": 75000,
      "image": "s-l300.webp",
      "search": [],
      "createdAt": "2024-02-18T17:55:08.414Z",
      "updatedAt": "2024-02-18T17:55:08.414Z",
      "__v": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Aggregate:
This code gets me very close to what I desire. However, it attaches the result card array and overwrites the catagory.cards array instead of only updating based on 'users.catagory.cards._id' === 'cards._id'.

```
const results = await User.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'cards',
        localField: 'catagory.cards',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'cards'
      }
    },
    {
      $addFields: { 'catagory.cards': '$cards' }
    }
  ],
  { maxTimeMS: 60000, allowDiskUse: true }
);
```

I tried using a filter but this was not successful.

```
{
  "catagory.cards": {
            $filter: {
               input: "$catagory.cards",
               as: "card",
               cond: { $in: [ "$$card._id", "$catagory.cards"] }
            }
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all would be great to see the question - what exactly you would like to achieve. For now, let me try with some guess, and let me know if it helps. Otherwise please provide with more specific expectations, so that I can update the answer.

First thing I noted is `localField` in your example in $lookup has `'catagory.cards'`, while it should be `'catagory.cards._id'` as you match only by `_id` field, not by the whole record.
Also, noticed a typo "catagory" instead of "category". If it wasn't intentional - please be careful, because it might be root of some issues if you'll write `category` in other part of code.

Now let me guess you would like to see all card details inside array items of `category.cards` field.

That can be achieved by:

- `$unwind`-ing arrays into separate records (we have to unwind categories into separate records to have each category in each record, then unwind category cards to have each card in separate record),
- then matching them with card details by `$lookup` into `category.cards` field (so that it will override that field for each record - and that's why it was important to have each record per each category card),
- and then combine those records back to one record again (by grouping by category, then grouping by user to have the record structure the same is it was initially).

Please note in `$unwind` I used flag `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true`, otherwise it would throw away items without unwinding children (in your example: category "baseball").

```js
db.User.aggregate([
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$catagory',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }}, 
    { $unwind: {
        path: '$catagory.cards',
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }}, 
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'cards',
        localField: 'catagory.cards._id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'catagory.cards'
    }},
  { $group: {
      _id: '$catagory._id',
      userId: { $first: '$_id' },
      categoryId: { $first: '$catagory._id' },
      name: { $first: '$catagory.name' },
      createdAt: { $first: '$catagory.createdAt' },
      cards: { $push: { $arrayElemAt: ['$catagory.cards', 0] } }
  }},
  { $group: {
      _id: '$userId',
      catagory: { $addToSet: {
          _id: '$categoryId',
          name: '$name',
          createdAt: '$createdAt',
          cards: '$cards'
      }},
  }},
]);
```

I tried it and it provides me the following output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("65d3d362c2006d4572b028a3"),
    "catagory" : [
        {
            "_id" : "65bc1176cfb7da6997273ae3",
            "name" : "test",
            "createdAt" : "2024-02-01T21:47:34.215Z",
            "cards" : [
                {
                    "_id" : "65c43a9539206da4c953e334",
                    "title" : "PSA 9 1996 Topps Finest Gold w/ Coating #269 Kobe Bryant Rookie Card",
                    "date" : "2023-11-16T05:00:00.000Z",
                    "price" : NumberInt(125000),
                    "image" : "s-l300.webp",
                    "search" : [

                    ],
                    "createdAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "updatedAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "65c43a9539206da4c953e32e",
                    "title" : "1996-97 Topps Finest Bronze Refractor #74 Kobe Bryant (RC) PSA 7 W/ Coating",
                    "date" : "2024-02-01T05:00:00.000Z",
                    "price" : NumberInt(130000),
                    "image" : "s-l300.webp",
                    "search" : [

                    ],
                    "createdAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "updatedAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "65c43a9539206da4c953e332",
                    "title" : "1996-97 Fleer Ultra Series 2 Basketball Factory Sealed Hobby Box-Kobe Bryant RC?",
                    "date" : "2023-11-28T05:00:00.000Z",
                    "price" : NumberInt(124999),
                    "image" : "s-l300.webp",
                    "search" : [

                    ],
                    "createdAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "updatedAt" : "2024-02-08T02:21:09.344Z",
                    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
                },
                {
                    "_id" : "65d2447cbad1f058de61ecca",
                    "title" : "HUGE SPORTS CARD COLLECTION! 2023 CJ Stroud Justin Herbert Rookie Auto RPA READ",
                    "date" : "2024-02-17T05:00:00.000Z",
                    "price" : NumberInt(75000),
                    "image" : "s-l300.webp",
                    "search" : [

                    ],
                    "createdAt" : "2024-02-18T17:55:08.414Z",
                    "updatedAt" : "2024-02-18T17:55:08.414Z",
                    "__v" : NumberInt(0)
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "_id" : "65bc256ecfb7da6997273c71",
            "name" : "baseball",
            "createdAt" : "2024-02-01T23:12:46.996Z",
            "cards" : [

            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Please let me know if that's result you want to achieve, and if you have any questions or prefer any further clarifications.

Welcome!

**UPDATE**

Here is the MongoPlayground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Fd8KLywV4v

Comment: The result you created is perfect! I'm just not getting it. I got an empty object with 1 _id.

Comment: Here is MongoPlayground, please check your data structure is the same (because it was not very clear from description - I suppose there are two collections `User` and `cards`, but please check with playground for sure), and feel free to test the script above: https://mongoplayground.net/p/4Fd8KLywV4v

Comment: I checked with playground and updated the collections in my question. https://mongoplayground.net/p/sdIpoImaFrn The result structurally looks correct. the cards array is being created, but the array is not being populated in my result.

Comment: Normally `_id: { $oid: "...." }` is internal representation of ObjectID, but I'm confusing about having `$oid` out of _id object in your `catagory.cards`: `"cards": [{ "$oid": "65c43a9539206da4c953e334" },...`
Have you missed wrapping `_id` for each of items above? Also, for `User` collection you have everywhere `{ _id: { $iod: "....." } }` while for `cards` it's just `{ _id: "....." }`. Is that different structures of _id for them? If so, then I'd prefer to have this question marked as solved (initial requirement resolved) and have a separate question with issues about `_id` structures.

Comment: Would it be because my schema has cards as a REF?

    `
catagory: [
      {
        name: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
        cards: {
          type: ObjectId,
          ref: "Card",
        },
        createdAt: {
          type: Date,
          required: true,
        },
      },
`

Comment: Thank you! Can you please double check the link to the new question? I get: Page not found
This question was voluntarily removed by its author.